# Can a Twitter URL specify how many pages or entries to show?

Tags: twitter

Right now, the link

> https://twitter.com/itunescarddeals

will show the first page of content, and when the user scrolls down, then Twitter will add more content to the end of the page.

Is there a way to use a URL, possibly by adding params to the URL, so that Twitter will show 20 or 30 entries, or 2 pages of content to begin with?

Comment: Don't know if there's a way to do that with URL parameters, but you could do it with a bookmarklet (or browser extension, to run it automatically). You'd just need to throw in a little bit of JavaScript to scroll down past the edge of the page -- to load more content -- then scroll back up to the top. Would probably only be a few lines of code.